# Java Regex remove new lines, but keep spaces.

Tags: java, regex

For the string `" \n a   b c \n 1  2   3 \n x y  z "` I need it to become `"a b c 1 2 3 x y z"`.

Using this regex str.replaceAll("(\s|\n)", ""); I can get "abc123xyz", but how can I get spaces in between.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't have to use regex; you can use `trim()` and `replaceAll()` instead.

```
 String str = " \n a b c \n 1 2 3 \n x y z ";
 str = str.trim().replaceAll("\n ", "");
```

This will give you the string that you're looking for.

Comment: @pmartin8 Wanna tell that to the OP who was satisfied with this?

Answer (score 7):

This will remove all spaces and newline characters

```
String oldName ="2547 789 453 ";
String newName = oldName.replaceAll("\\s", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
str = str.replaceAll("^ | $|\\n ", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this with Regex, this probably would do the trick for you

```
String str = " \n a b c \n 1 2 3 \n x y z ";

str = str.replaceAll("^\\s|\n\\s|\\s$", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pretty simple and straightforward example of how I would do it

```
String string = " \n a   b c \n 1  2   3 \n x y  z "; //Input
string = string                     // You can mutate this string
    .replaceAll("(\s|\n)", "")      // This is from your code
    .replaceAll(".(?=.)", "$0 ");   // This last step will add a space
                                    // between all letters in the 
                                    // string...
```

You could use this sample to verify that the last regex works:

```
class Foo {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String str = "FooBar";
        System.out.println(str.replaceAll(".(?=.)", "$0 "));
    }
}
```

Output: "F o o B a r"

More info on lookarounds in regex here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

This approach makes it so that it would work on any string input and it is merely one more step added on to your original work, as to answer your question accurately. Happy Coding :)