# Replace newline and extra spaces

Tags: java, android, regex

I have text that is something like this:

```
[spaces] This is a [spaces]  line [spaces] [newline]<br/>  
which has been [spaces] broken [newline]<br/> 
[newline]<br/> 
[newline]<br/> 
into multiple part[spaces] [newline]<br/>
```

I want to:

- remove single newline with a space
- remove multiple newline with single newline
- remove multiple-white spaces with single white space
- keep single white spaces as they are.

So text above should be like this:

```
This is a line which has been broken<br/>
into multiple part.
```

I am using java (for android app). I have tried a few solutions here on SO but only `trim()` seems to work which strips spaces at beginning and the end of text. Other `ReplaceAll()` ways don't work in my case.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you.

**UPDATE**
I used this code:
`replaceAll("\n", " ").replaceAll("[\n]{2,}", "\n").replaceAll(" +", " ")`

But it is not working as expected.

It seems I need something that would do all these three replacements simultaneously instead of passing string from one to another `replaceAll()`

It should see if there are two of more `\n` then replace it with one `\n` AND if there was already only one `\n` then replace that with a space.

I think I should first replace two or more `\n` with some word like TWOFEEDS and then replace single `\n` with space. After that I again replace TWOFEEDS  with just one `\n`

**UPDATE 2**
This works as expected. But I am not sure how slow it will be when I pass it 7200 text records from DB table.

`replaceAll("[\n]{2,}", "TWOFEEDS").replaceAll("\n", " ").replaceAll(" +", " ").replaceAll("<br/>", "\n").replaceAll("TWOFEEDS", "\n")`

If there is anyway to improve please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: regex was born to solve this problem.  Learn about regular expressions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31032620/5281666

Answer (score 8):

Using **Regex** you can remove extra spaces and lines.

Code:

```
String text = text.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

This will give you the output you have expected.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It removes multiple newlines with spaces too. I would like to replace multiple newlines with single newline.

Thank you.

Comment: Can't understand your question. what is your expected output?

Comment: My bad. I updated the expected output. 

Two or more `\n'` should be replaced with only one. One `\n` should be replaced with one space. 

And two or more spaces should be replaced with one space.

Comment: @BhuvaneshBS - could you please explain the regex ?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs answer to this kind of question then I have finally settled with this

`replaceAll("\n", " ").replaceAll("[\n]{2,}", "\n").replaceAll(" +", " ")`

This is working good even for 7k records. Also, you may want to use `trim()` before applying above `replaceAll()` use it like yourtext.trim().replaceAll....(basically above code)

Comment: Why using 3 `replaceAll` when a single one is enough?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this,** to replace multiple new lines with single new line:

```
yourStr.replaceAll("[\r\n]+", "\r\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ')`

```
`example   .
  text`.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
```