# Removing the newline characters in a string using Regex java

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I am new to regular expressions in java. I have a `csv` file which consists of newline characters in some of the fields like below:

```
name,address,phone
tom,123 baker st,1234
jim,"234 baker st
some city",5678
james,"897 lowell st
some city, some state",78910
```

If a particular value has `commas` or `newlines`, the whole value is enclosed between `" "`. I need to remove the newline characters (and replace it with a single space) in the fields and I think using a regex would be easier.

hoping it would make it easier, I have read the whole file into a String using the below lines:

```
String str = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("file path")),"UTF-8");
```

Now I have the whole file in `str`. All the fields are separated by commas. so, any newline characters between `,"` and `",` in the string `str` should be removed (replaced with `" "`).I am guessing I should write a regex to match this pattern and then replace the `newlines('\n')` with `" "`.

My knowledge ends there and I have no clue how to implement it in my code.

after the transformation, the data should look like this:

```
name,address,phone
tom,123 baker st,1234
jim,"234 baker st some city",5678
james,"897 lowell st some city, some state",78910
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: use CSVParser for parsing with fields delimited by `,` and enclosed by `"`

Comment: I need the whole data as a new file without the `newline` characters in the fields like I mentioned in my question. Can it be done using the parser? If yes, can you please link an example?

Comment: @Hemnath you can parse with `CSVParser` and replace `\r\n` with empty string for the fields you want to remove new line

Comment: There will me multiple fields which contain newlines and it differs for every record. Is that still possible? I think using a regex to replace newlines in the string would be easier..@Saravana

Comment: It's probably possible using zero-width lookahead and lookbehind assertions in the regex, but they'll become very complex - you also need to take into account that a CSV cell can contain double quotes, and they'll be escaped as two double-quote characters in sequence (`""`) and these don't terminate the value. Saravana's suggestion is much better.

Comment: I am thinking more in terms of Alex's answer. Having read the whole data into the string, using that approach seems to be much easier and concise. @ErwinBolwidt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CSVParser` to parse and remove space after reading the fields

```
CSVFormat format = CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                .withRecordSeparator(',')
                .withIgnoreEmptyLines()
                .withQuote('"');
        CSVParser parser = CSVParser.parse(new File("/file/path/csv"), Charset.defaultCharset(), format);
        List<CSVRecord> recordList = parser.getRecords();
        for (CSVRecord record : recordList) {
            Iterator<String> it = record.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                System.out.print(it.next().replace("\n", "") + "|");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

output

```
name|address|phone|
tom|123 baker st|1234|
jim|234 baker stsome city|5678|
james|897 lowell stsome city, some state|78910|
```

maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I came here expecting to get an answer using the regex, but I have to say, it's a brilliant answer. working perfectly! Thank you! just one thing though, is there a way I can avoid putting `|` at the end of each line?

Comment: @Hemanth if you see the sysout statement, I am contacting `|` for readability, you can remove it

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Here is a solution

```
str.replaceAll("(,\".*)(\n+)(.*\",)", "$1 $3")
```

Here is a good tutorial explaining grouping and back reference in regex in java http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#grouping-and-back-reference

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I strictly need to replace only the newlines between `,"` and `",` . Does the above code still work? or do we have to do something like this: `str.replaceAll("(,\".*\",)(\n+)", "$1 ")`

Comment: updated the proposed code in the answer. it replaces only newlines between ," and ",

Comment: It's working perfectly for the sample data in the question.But, on my actual data, most of the newlines are still present. Any idea why this is happening?      My actual data also consists of special characters between `,"` and `,"` . could that be causing an issue?

Comment: @AlexBinkovsky, just a thought. As Hemanth, wants to replace the text till the number. So should this be a better expression for that --
`str.replaceAll("(,\".+)(\n+)(.+\",\d+)", "$1 $3")`   ??

Comment: I only posted the above data as a sample. It's not like I'll have a number after `",` in the actual data. @Abhishek

Comment: @Hemanth, you may have it right ?? If you do, then you can tweak my previous expression like this - 
`str.replaceAll("(,\".+)(\n+)(.+\",\d*)", "$1 $3")`. Otherwise, Alex's expression will give you the right results. :)

Answer (score -1):

[Java Regex removing spaces and new line character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12015172/java-regex-removing-spaces-and-new-line-character)

```
String str = " \n a b c \n 1 2 3 \n x y z ";
str = str.trim().replaceAll("\n ", "");
```

Comment: I won't be able to use this as I don't want to replace all the newlines in the string. only the newlines between `,"` and `",`

Comment: The OP doesn't want to remove all newline characters- in fact he needs to keep most of them to separate the lines. OP only wants to remove newline characters within the double quotes of a single value in the CSV.